# Visual Studio 2015 deletes Web Deploy wpp.targets file

Tags: visual-studio, delete-file, webdeploy

When ever my teammates do a Web Deploy of our MVC5 site from Visual Studio 2015, it deletes the custom wpp.targets file of that project. What could be the reason?

[image: Web Deploy wpp.targets]

Edit 1: I created this wpp.targets file and tested that it works and checked it in. The VS in my machine does not delete it. But when my teammates do a publish, it deletes that wpp.targets file.

There is [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026575/visual-studio-2015-web-deploy-always-deletes-a-specific-file-all-the-time) SO question that states a similar problem. But setting the 'Build Action' settings in properties to 'Content' instead of 'None' did not solve this deletion issue.

Comment: Never seen that before.  Where are you deploying to?

Comment: Deploying to IIS in localhost. I will edit the question with more details.

Comment: Is the wwp.targets removed from the developers local project folder or the target IIS folder?  Did you checkin your csproj file after changing the build action to "Content"?

Comment: @chief7 VS is deleting the file in local project folder, for my teammates. Yes, I checked in the csproj into the VSO git repo after changing the build action to 'Content'.

Comment: Does this only happen in VS2015?  Can you try in older versions?